# SelectNextControl not working on telerik drop down list

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

VS 2017 - Windows Form app - Current Telerik Controls

I have a form that I want the user to be able to move to the next control by pressing Enter (or Tab).
The Tab works correctly.

To enable the enter functionality I am doing this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{      
    if (ActiveControl.Name.ToString() != "order_creation_grid") //ensures that we don't caputre keypresses in the grid
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.SelectNextControl((Control)ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
```

and that works fine, except for in a drop down list box.
I think it is because the list box used Enter to select the current item.
So, I tried to do the following to check if I am in that control and just manually select the proper control:

```
if (ActiveControl.Name.ToString() != "order_creation_grid") //ensures that we don't caputre keypresses in the grid
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {

            if (ActiveControl.Name.ToString() == "order_address_dd")
            {
                order_city_eb.Select();
            }
            else
            {
                this.SelectNextControl((Control)ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
            }
    }
```

The problem is that ActiveControl.Name is not being set - it shows "".

The ActiveControl.SelectedItem DOES show the text in the drop down that is selected so I am assuming that I am looking in the right place.

btw...the event does fire off as expected, the SelectNextControl is not working.
Update: I have a workaround in place, but I am sure this is not the *correct* way to solve this:

```
if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_address_dd")
{
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
}
else
{
    this.SelectNextControl((Control)ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enough time has passed if there was a better way to do this I assume somebody would have posted it.

This is the solution I am using and it is working fine:

```
if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_address_dd")
{
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
}
else
{
    this.SelectNextControl((Control)ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```